# keeping the selected date after page reload in jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

is there a better (more elegant way - in datepicker itself maybe?) way to set the last selected date in datepicker after page reload than to fill the cookie after each date select and then inputing the date from cookie to datepicker on reload.

**edit:** 
question rephrase: 
is there a better (more elegant way - in datepicker itself maybe?) way to set the last selected date in datepicker after page reload.

The way I am doing it now is: once the date is selected in the datepicker I set the cookie, and then when the page reloads I set the current datepicker value to the one from the cookie (if available).

Now, what I was asking is: is there an option in datepicker to do this more elegantly like for example this:

```
$("dateWrapper").datepicker({cookie:'yes'});
```

Comment: Try to re-word it. Maybe give some examples... codewise

Comment: Nikola tebra, you have to use cookies, or HTML5 web database if the browser supports it (like WebKit), or send it back to server, and on page reload/ajax get the last value (which is the same as cookie/client_db is only now you are hogging the internet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can post your date to session variable via ajax & put it into value in HTML
- You can save it to cookies

Comment: I am doing it this way already, I was just asking if there is maybe a "more elegant" way of doing this?